# Login with ajax shadow

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm building this website with a Wordpress base. I use a Login-with-Ajax plugin to create the login pop-out.

When I added a simple php `wp-nav-menu` command (manually added in single pages using `[insert_php]` the nav bar doesn't disappear behind the shadow the login pop-out creates.

You can see what I mean in siodental.com and clicking on Acceder/Registrarse

I tried asking in the plugin support forum but its pretty dead.

The code I added in every page I want my menu on is:

```
[insert_php]wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'info','theme_location' => 'Main Navigation',
     'container_id' => 'cssmenu',   'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker()) );[/insert_php]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to simply use z-index:0 on my nav menu css!